# React -> Auth0 to authorize user -> then call AWS API Gateway: best way to authenticate with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway

We have a React app that starts by authenticating a user via Auth0 login. Once the user is authenticated, we know their organization, and can use that to make a request from our app via AWS API Gateway to an AWS Lambda function.

I am trying to see if there's a simpler way to authenticate with AWS API Gateway than the one we use now, since it no longer works with most browsers.

The current approach uses the token passed by Auth0 in the initial auth request to call a whole new and different authentication process for AWS API Gateway. There's a custom authorizer for Lambda, and various different kinds of tokens are used to make another call to Auth0 -- ones for the standard user auth, and then another approach for Lambda. This is complicated, and we're running into problems with CORS after changing to use a "custom" domain presented by Auth0 when the user authenticates. I can probably figure out how to make it work, but in general, this seems entirely unnecessary.

That is: prior to making any requests to API Gateway, I have

- an authenticated user
- in a secure browser session
- at a known domain and endpoints
- that can only be accessed by authenticated users
- all the information I need to make the Gateway API request.

I am looking at API Gateway docs and it appears I can [create a resource policy with a condition key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-aws-condition-keys.html) that checks `aws:SecureTransport`. Perhaps I could also add a check that `aws:referer` matches expected domain and endpoint to be sure.

Given this scenario is there any reason not to use this seemingly far simpler approach to authorizing API Gateway requests?